# How to Find Date and Time a Stock Traded at a Certain Price

Tags: stocks, price

I am trying to see when Disney was traded at 79.07.

When I see graph on Google, it shows Year-to-Date lowest point is Mar 23rd trading at 85.98.

How do I see (1) Date and (2) Time when stock was 79.07?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph that  you posted is a closing price line graph so it does not depict the high or the low price.

The lowest low price this year was $79.07 on 3/18.

The lowest closing price this year was $85.76 on 3/23.

You can see this in the historical data at [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS/history?p=DIS).  My Thomson Reuters data shows  the same prices.